# JPA One-To-Many Relationship Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am new in Spring Boot and I have a class Student.java and another Project.java. Each student can have multiple projects (the relationship is 1:M). I want to map them, and I have the following:

In Student.java :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
private List of projects;
```

In Project.java :

```
@ManyToOne <br>
@JoinColumn(name=student_id)
private Student student;
```

I know that `@JoinColumn` adds a column in the *project* table in the database, but I don't understand what does **mappedBy** do? I found this: "*mappedBy indicates the entity is the inverse of the relationship.*" What does **the inverse of the relationship** mean?

I tried the code in the database, and when I don't have the mappedBy I get 3 tables in the database (a different table that contains projectId and studentId), but I don't understand how that works. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#mappedBy() for more details.

> The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

It tells **JPA** to go around and find if is there any bean property with name `student` and use this configuration.
In your code, it will find a configuration in `Project` entity.